# Windows 10 only boots after running chkdsk /f

Tags: windows-10, chkdsk, safe-mode

We have a PC with Windows 10 which boots up until it gets to the Windows restore options. Once I get into them, I can go to the Advanced startup options and reboot it in Safe Mode with CMD prompt. There I enter the "chkdsk /f" command, reboot the PC and after the checkdisk is finished it boots up normally. But with the next reboot, the whole story starts over. Anyone that has an idea of things that I can try/do to get this fixed?

Comment: maybe the hard drive is failing.

Comment: Strangely enough it is working everytime after the chkdsk